# How do you change the automatically created password?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I've got a Cloudant service that is associated with my Bluemix app. When it was setup, a username/password combo was created automatically. I accidentally shared the credentials (it is just a demo), so now I want to change the password. As far as I can see, there is no way to actually change the password - either on the dashboard or the site itself. Where is this done?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general website tech support.

Comment: Fair point - I'll close it myself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the cloudant service, and not a programming q.

Answer (score 2):

There is no UI to change your credentials. You can contact support. I recommend you create a new instance, use the Replication tab in the Cloudant console to migrate your database, and then delete the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Service credentials are usually created by binding the service instance to an application. Not every service broker works this way, but most do. Simply unbinding the service:

```
cf unbind-service myapp myservice-instance
```

And then rebinding:

```
cf bind-service myapp myservice-instance
```

Should result in new credentials being generated to the same service instance. Since you can bind a service to multiple applications, each application generally gets different credentials (depending on the service broker implementation).

Comment: Oh man - I wish I had known this. Well, it wasn't too hard to replicate. Thanks!